# How to create doc/docx file manually in java

Tags: java, docx

I create a docx file with pure string in java.
 when I send email the docx file to my phone, file can not be opened properly.

My java code is:

```
// creating a docx file
File wordFile = new File("myDocFile.docx");
wordFile.createNewFile();

 String title   = "my document title here";
 String content = "my document content here";

 // docx file content with Html
String fileStr = "<!DOCTYPE html><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" " +
" content=\"application/msword; charset=UTF-8\">" + 
"<h1 style='text-align:center;'>" + title+ "</h1>" + content;

// writing fileStr in to docx file.
   Files.write(wordFile.toPath(), fileStr.getBytes("UTF-8"),
   StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
```

My docx file that created is not be opened in smart phone.
How can I do docx to be read in smart phone?

Comment: you can't. docx is a Word format, not all smartphones have Word installed/active

Comment: For starters DOCX is a compressed format. Use something like docx4j (https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) to create these files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two simple misconceptions here:

- sure, docx has *open XML* content, but still you shouldn't try to create such files *manually*, use a reasonable library, such as [apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/). Seriously: you start with a simple "body", but anything that is useful in the real world grows. Your requirements will turn more complex quickly, and then you spend a lot of time re-implementing what such libraries do for you. Re-inventing wheels is costly, especially given the fact that *your* wheel will really suck compared to any mature library for that job.
- *How can I do docx to be read in every smart phone?* You can't. You have **no** control over "every" smart phone in the world, thus you can't enforce that the person receiving your docx is able to view it.

Long story short: your whole approach looks "broken by design". Many people really don't like being send "office" files (for good security reasons that is).

So, the real answer is: step back, and evaluate what kind of information you want to "send out", and then figure ways that actually *work* for all your users.

When you are already sending them emails, consider putting some good old plain text into them. In general: sending emails with files attached to them is a *great* way of annoying your users. It should be your last resort, not your first.